# for-loop interferes with others in web.py

Tags: for-loop, web.py

I'm a newbie in web.py.

In my template script exists two FOR loops,it seems that the former(**code1**) interferes the later one(**code2**).Each one of them displays well alone,but abnormal when they are in one template script.

**code1**

```
$for data in posts:

<div id="title">
<h2><a href="/view/$data.id">$data.title</a></h2>
</div>

<div id="marker">
<p>
<a href="/about"> User </a>
$data.post_on<a href="/catalog/$data.catalog"> $data.catalog</a>
</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>$data.content</p>
</div>
```

**code2**

```
$for (cat,ctr) in catcollector(posts).items():
<ul>
<li><a href="/catalog/$cat">$cat</a> ($ctr)</li>
</ul>
```

I'm confused with this phenomenon.Does any one have idea about this? Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is your only problem, but it looks like your indentations are not correct.  Things within the for loop should be indented.